# How to set up simple database replication using WAMP server?

Tags: mysql

Just need a little help here about replication. I have an intermediate knowledge in Mysql. And I can't find any simple solutions on web how to establish a database replication in Mysql. All I need to do is to create a back up from my master database to my localhost.
For example if I have a master database on **192.145.114.12** and a database **'myorg_site'** and in my localhost I have database **'bk_myorg_site'**. **Any changes in the table data in myorg_site will change as well in bk_myorg_site.** Can you provide me a simple instruction for that? Starting from mysql configuration? That's all guys I hope you can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Replication setup is very easy, please follow these steps to make proper replication setup:

1) Backup your Master server's data as:

> mysqldump --all-databases --master-data > dbdump.db

2) Import this backup file on Slave server

3) Create a user in Master server to connect to Slave

> GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.*  TO 'repl'@'slaveip'
>    IDENTIFIED BY 'slavepassword';

4) Edit Slave server and give server-id to something other that Maser server_id in my.ini file as well specify `replicate_do_db` as database you want to replicate from Master.

This will replication only database which you want to replicate to slave server, other database from Master will be skipped for replication

5) Execute this query on Master and get it's filename and position

> Show Master status;

6) Now execute this query on Slave

> CHANGE MASTER TO
>                   MASTER_HOST='masterip',
>                   MASTER_USER='slave_user',
>                   MASTER_PASSWORD='slavepass',
>                   MASTER_LOG_FILE='Master-bin.000001',
>                   MASTER_LOG_POS=101;

7) Now execute this on slave

> Start Slave;

You are done with your replication

8) To check your replication status execute this query on Slave server:

> Show slave status;