# MySQL Replication

Tags: mysql, replication

i try to search around the internet to find out what's a "Master -> Slave" Replication of MySQL want to do?

Can sombardey maby explain it for me?

what i can read is what happen are when i have a master -> slave set up i can only write to 1 server here the master and when i need to read data out i read from master ip and the master self tell all the slaves server to delivery data to my master server there now delivery data to my software.

can sombardey explain me now about i'm right or i'm wrong understand Mater -> Slave replication set up?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at one of my answer here about how to setup replication in easy steps:

[How to set up simple database replication using WAMP server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53878/how-to-set-up-simple-database-replication-using-wamp-server/53884#53884)

You can point your application to Master server for writing purpose and for reading purpose point application to Slave server(s).

This will help in balancing the load of application and hence you can achieve better performance.

Comment: Hmmm so what you say is Master split all read load to all slave server if i understand you current?